# Removed second monitor when laptop screen was disabled monitor stays off

Tags: 18.04, lubuntu

So today I was given an unpleasant surprise. I have a second monitor at home and disable the main monitor on my laptop when I’m at home. Unfortunately I did not reenable the laptop monitor while I was using the external monitor. So now my laptop monitor is disabled and I can’t reenable it due to not being able to see anything. How do I fix this short of finding a monitor with hdmi or going home.

Is there a terminal command I can type blindly using the ctrl alt f6 terminal.

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: I can boot into recovery mode and the screen starts normally but in my normal boot the screen is still off.

Comment: you're very welcome. I made an answer please mark and upvote, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Booting into failsafe mode AKA recovery mode by holding down the <kbd>left Shift</kbd> key as the computer starts to boot (If holding the Shift key doesn't display the menu press the <kbd>Esc</kbd>) should solve your issue.

Once you're in with a display you can do whatever suits you to get your screen back in normal boot mode.

you can for example reinstall graphics driver or change screen settings.

Comment: this worked booting into recovery mode then changing the screen settings.